# Generate random numbers spaced at least 10 apart

Tags: r, random, numbers

I want to generate 100 numbers from 1 to 100,000, where the space between each is at least 10.

One way is to divide 100,000 by 10, and do the sample(1000,100) and get the answer, times 10, but the numbers all end with 0.

How do I generate random numbers not only ending with 0?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't come up with a non-recursive way to do this (first thought was to add "jiggles" to your approach, but this will almost surely bring some observations too close to one another), but this will work:

```
set.seed(102438)
include <- 1:100000
smpl <- integer(100)

for (i in 1:length(smpl)){
  smpl[i] <- si <- sample(include, 1)
  #now remove anything within 10 of the current draw
  include <- setdiff(include, (si - 10L):(si + 10L))
}

min(abs(diff(smpl)))
# [1] 1105
```

Answer (score 2):

Try rejection sampling.  Perform the sampling without restriction and if any two are less than 10 apart throw the result away and do it again until it succeeds:

```
repeat {
  s <- sample(100000, 100)
  mindiff <- min(diff(sort(s)))
  if (mindiff >= 10) break
}
```

It's not clear from the wording of the question if differences of successive numbers when sorted must be 10 or greater or whether they must be greater than 10.  I have assumed the former but use > in the if statement if it is the latter.

**Example** Starting from the seed 123 the loop takes only 3 iterations (compared to 100 and 100,000 iterations for the other answers).  Below we have added a `set.seed` statement for reproducibility and a `print` statement so we can see how many iterations are used.

```
set.seed(123)
repeat {
  s <- sample(100000, 100)
  mindiff <- min(diff(sort(s)))
  print(mindiff)
  if (mindiff >= 10) break
}
```

giving:

```
[1] 8
[1] 1
[1] 17
```

Comment: I think this approach will be very quick for small (n_desired / n_initial --i.e., 100 / 100000 here), but will reject  frequently as that rises. mine suffers from another flaw -- it will fail if we run out of available draws (by pigeonhole, this must happen if n_desired > n_initial/10, roughly, but will happen for the vast majority of draw paths as n_desired approaches that bound)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @G.Grothendieck I suppose, repeat sampling but reject if it doesn't meet your criteria.

```
set.seed(1337)

## minimum separation
min_gap <- 10

## first entry
samp_vec <- sample(seq(1,1e5L,1), 1)
for (isamp in 1:100) { 

  possible_new_value <- samp_vec[1]
  while(any(abs(samp_vec - possible_new_value) < min_gap)) {
    possible_new_value <- sample(seq(1,1e5L,1), 1)
  }
  samp_vec <- c(samp_vec, possible_new_value)


}

min(abs(diff(samp_vec)))
# 92
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that does not rely on recursion:

```
mysample <- function(n, lower, upper, space) {
  b <- ceiling((upper - lower + 1) / (space - 1))
  bs <- sample(seq(2, b - 1, by = 2), n - 1)
  gr <- split(setdiff(1:b,bs), cumsum(c(0, diff(setdiff(1:b, bs))) != 1))
  out <- sapply(gr, function(x) (x[1] - 1) * (space - 1) + ceiling(runif(1) * length(x) * (space - 1)))
  out[n] <- min(out[n], upper)
  out
}

set.seed(123)
min(replicate(min(diff(mysample(100, 1, 100000, 10))), n = 1000))
# [1] 10
```

`mysample` returns an already sorted sequence, but of course you may use `sample(mysample(...))`.

The idea of the function is to divide the interval [lower, upper] to blocks of length `space - 1` and to sample `n-1` blocks from 2th, 4th, 6th, ... blocks; these will be "forbidden" blocks, i.e. we will not have any numbers from these blocks. Then the remaining, "permitted" blocks could be e.g. 1st, 2nd, 5th; in this case we have two groups of consecutive blocks (1st and 2nd; 5th) and we sample two numbers from the intervals that correspond to these two groups of blocks. I also added a small check whether the largest number goes above the upper limit.

Some results:

```
set.seed(123)
upper <- 100000
benchmark(
  mysample(100, 1, upper, 10), MichaelChirico(100, 1, upper, 10), 
  Grothendieck(100, 1, upper, 10), Jonathan(100, 1, upper, 10), 
  replications = 1, columns = c("test", "relative"))
#                                    test relative
# 3   Grothendieck(100, lower, upper, 10)        1
# 4       Jonathan(100, lower, upper, 10)      344
# 2 MichaelChirico(100, lower, upper, 10)     2133
# 1       mysample(100, lower, upper, 10)        4

upper <- 10000
benchmark(
  mysample(100, 1, upper, 10), MichaelChirico(100, 1, upper, 10), 
  Grothendieck(100, 1, upper, 10), Jonathan(100, 1, upper, 10), 
  replications = 1, columns = c("test", "relative"))
#                                    test relative
# 3   Grothendieck(100, lower, upper, 10)    132.5
# 4       Jonathan(100, lower, upper, 10)     56.0
# 2 MichaelChirico(100, lower, upper, 10)     27.5
# 1       mysample(100, lower, upper, 10)      1.0
```

where

```
MichaelChirico <- function(n, lower, upper, space) {
  include <- lower:upper
  smpl <- integer(n)
  for (i in 1:length(smpl)){
    smpl[i] <- si <- sample(include, 1)
    include <- setdiff(include, (si - space):(si + space))
  }
  smpl
}

Grothendieck <- function(n, lower, upper, space) {
  repeat {
    s <- sample(lower:upper, n)
    mindiff <- min(diff(sort(s)))
    if (mindiff >= space) break
  }
  s
}

Jonathan <- function(n, lower, upper, space) {
  min_gap <- space
  samp_vec <- sample(seq(lower,upper,1), 1)
  for (isamp in 1:n) {
    possible_new_value <- samp_vec[1]
    while(any(abs(samp_vec - possible_new_value) < min_gap)) {
      possible_new_value <- sample(seq(lower,upper,1), 1)
    }
    samp_vec <- c(samp_vec, possible_new_value)
  }
  samp_vec
}
```

Comment: nice approach. you should randomize whether even or odd are the "forbidden" blocks (i.e., `seq(sample(2, 1), b - 1, by = 2)`)-- you still won't get the universe of possible "valid" samples, but you'll get a lot closer

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I agree that my solution could be improved in this direction, but by considering odd blocks there could be some complications and I decided to avoid them. Here is what I mean; suppose that `n = 3` and in total there are 5 blocks. By making blocks 2 and 4 forbidden we get the result, although not a perfect one, by sampling one number from each of blocks 1, 3, 5. By making blocks 1, 3 and 5 forbidden, we might have to sample 3 numbers from the group of blocks 3, 4, 5, where a failure is possible.